# C# windows application set up on different machines and all work on one SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: c#

I have created a desktop application with SQL Server 2008 as backend. I want to use this database from my application that is installed on a number of machines.

What are the requirements for that application to connect to the centralized database.?

Comment: This question could be considered overly broad.  Are you just after how to do this or are you looking for information on how to deal with multiple users and resolving concurrent upates and locking. (e.g. what if two users make a change to the same record one after the other)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple, You want the architecture as Client-Server model were the server has the database .Hence you need to have MS SQLserver 2005 or higher versions and create database connect it to sqlserver. Grant permission for the clients to access the database.

From visual studio side:
Add the above created .mdf(database file) as the new data source. 
Data-->Add new Data Source , and follow the steps in the wizard[p.s the type of connection has to be sql sever type ] 
while doing this a connection string will be created by VS. Use tht connection string to access from the client side.

This link would be useful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxds9ett(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the details, How can i Grant permission for the Clients to access the database?and how can i Use the connection string to access from the client sides?

Comment: In MSSQLserver right click on the database file , go to properties there u will be able to grant permission. the usage of connection string is answered by @AgentFire

Comment: I should check the check boxes for my Users?to grant the permissions?any suggestions?

Comment: i checked all the check boxes, it doesn't make any problem?i mean the grants.

Comment: choose the permissions based on your requirements,take data safety into account.

Comment: Thank you so much, i shall do my tests and will inform you back if my issue is sorted out.

Comment: Now i'm working on it, i can't access my SQL server from client computer, on client computer i choose Network Servers Tab then it founds the SQL Server on the Server Machine, but when i press Connect it gives this error: Cannot connect to Server-PC\SQLEXPRESS. Additional Information: Login Failed for user 'Server-PC\Guest'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: 1. in SSMS on the Server we should make the remote connection possible. 2. turn on fire wall and add the programs you don't want the firewall to block it. 3. Server and Clients computers should be in the same domain. 4. In Protocols for SQLEXPRESS enable the TCP/IP. 5. Add Another Log in user for SSMS on the Server. 6. On Client Computer Use Server authentication and put the username and the password. then cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the connection string in its resources, ofcourse.

Resources are:

1. Doubleclick on project's **Properties** (at solution explorer).
2. Then **Settings** tab.
3. If there is no default setting file, create it by clicking the long link label.
4. Add a setting like "`ConnectionString`" with the value like "Data Source = ..." whatever.

Then you can run your sql scripts like:

```
SqlConnection conn =
    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
```

And go on.

Comment: could you please give some details?

Comment: On Server i don't have connection problem, on client computers i installed SQL Server 2008 Management and i want to access the database on the server via IP like: IP\SQLEXPRESS, but gives error that IP is refer to a computer that doesn't have permission to access it and consider it as Guest user account.

Comment: @Shamal i suppose you should grant neccessary permissions on the SQL server, man. For example, add remote user account (the one which you are running your client on) either to server's accounts or to AD (whatever) and grant the db_writer, db_reader permissions to authenticated user in SQL.

Comment: How to add Permissions for the Client computers to access sql Server database on Server side?